# Merging a legacy application's code history with git

Tags: git, merge

I just rewrote a simple Rails application. The previous version of my application has a long git commit history that I'd like to retain with this rewrite. I have not even initialized git in the rewritten application's root. How would you go about merging the two applications?

I have never attempted a git merge before, but I imagine that I will first have to initialize git in the rewritten application's root. From there I'm completely lost.

This is slightly off topic, but what is "the way" to import the legacy application's git configuration into the new one? Is it as easy as copying over the .git folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at git subtree merging:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html

http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html